# Parent bug or something else?

Tags: mesh, objects, parent

Every time I put a new object near the scene, and move it, everything else seem to move with it too. Like in the picture, I didn't even parent anything, but every time I put near the table and move it again, suddenly everything start follow it. Is this a bug or something?

I duplicate the light[image]

Moved it inside[image]

When I tried to move it everything seems to follow it. I didn't even parent it to anything. The same goes to everything I just add to to the scene
[image]

Comment: Look at your 3D viewport's header: you have proportional editing enabled.  So every time you move anything, everything nearby moves as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `Proportional Editing Objects`: (`O` on your keyboard as a shortcut)

[image]

Comment: omfg, i didnt know proportional editing can work in object mode too -,-

Comment: Me neither >-<, spotted the big circle overlay on your screenshot and it looked kinda familiar